# Use of Gradle Plugin in external .gradle file

Tags: gradle

**Background:** 
I'm trying to use the [gradle-dependency-graph-generator-plugin](https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-dependency-graph-generator-plugin) in a gradle build, and configure it with custom Generator configurations.  When I place the configuration within the _root.gradle, our root gradle project:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      maven {
        url artifactoryRepoURL + '/repo'
      }
   }
   dependencies {
      //... 
      classpath "com.vanniktech:gradle-dependency-graph-generator-plugin:0.5.0"
   }
}
//...
allprojects {
   //...
   apply plugin: "com.vanniktech.dependency.graph.generator"
   //...
}
```

...it works just fine.  (Though, Intellij reports errors in the import, it builds and runs both on command line and in the IDE)

**The Problem**
I'd like to put this code in a separate gradle file, just so it's not cluttering up the root project.  So I move the code to a dependencyGraph.gradle file, and include it with an

```
apply from: "$rootProject.projectDir/dependencyGraph.gradle"
```

However, I get compilation errors, class not found.  So I add the buildScript and dependencies/classpath from the root project file, and try again.  This time, it gives a class cast exception:

```
com.vanniktech.dependency.graph.generator.DependencyGraphGeneratorExtension$Generator cannot be cast to com.vanniktech.dependency.graph.generator.DependencyGraphGeneratorExtension$Generator
```

Its the same classname, so I assume this is some kind of classloader problem. So, how does one include a build script that references plugin classes into a project.gradle?

EDIT: 
Per – @EugenMartynov 's comment, the file looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url artifactoryRepoURL + '/repo'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.vanniktech:gradle-dependency-graph-generator-plugin:0.5.0"
    }

}

import com.vanniktech.dependency.graph.generator.DependencyGraphGeneratorPlugin
import com.vanniktech.dependency.graph.generator.DependencyGraphGeneratorExtension.Generator
import guru.nidi.graphviz.attribute.Color
import guru.nidi.graphviz.attribute.Style
import guru.nidi.graphviz.attribute.Label

def updateNode(node, dependency) {
    def group = dependency.getModuleGroup()
    def colorCodeFor = { starts, color ->
        if (group.startsWith(starts)) {
            node.add(Style.FILLED, Color.rgb(color))
            return color
        }
        return null
    }
    def color = colorCodeFor("commons", "#ff008c")
            ?: colorCodeFor("org.apache", "#ff008c")
            ?: colorCodeFor("org.springframework", "#6db33f")
            ?: colorCodeFor("javax", "#ff0000")
            ?: colorCodeFor("com.fasterxml", "#3a772e")
            ?: colorCodeFor("ch.qos.logback", "#ffd0a0")
            ?: colorCodeFor("", String.format("#%06x", Math.abs(group.hashCode()) % (255*255*255))) // base off the group

    return node
}

def colorCodedGenerator = new Generator(
        "ColorCoded", // Suffix for our Gradle task.
        { dependency -> true }, // filter
        { dependency -> true }, // Include transitive dependencies.
        { node, dependency -> updateNode(node, dependency) }, // Give them some color.
        { node, project ->node.add(Style.FILLED, Color.rgb("#2cc2e4")) }, // project nodes.
)


dependencyGraphGenerator {
    generators = [ Generator.ALL, colorCodedGenerator ]
}
```

and is applied within the allprojects block:

```
allprojects {
   ...
   apply plugin: "com.vanniktech.dependency.graph.generator"
   apply from: "$rootProject.projectDir/dependencyGraph.gradle"
   ...
}
```

though I also tried only within the root project.  As configured, I get:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
...
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'dar'.
> com.vanniktech.dependency.graph.generator.DependencyGraphGeneratorExtension$Generator cannot be cast to com.vanniktech.dependency.graph.generator.DependencyGraphGeneratorExtension$Generator
```

This is gradle 4.9, btw

Comment: How do you move it? Can you share the content of that file and how do you apply it?

Comment: Updated to include the information requested by @EugenMartynov

Comment: Looks like you have double class loaders or so, I'm not sure that you can also apply `buildscript` section in this way.

Comment: @EugenMartynov :  Agreed, but what is the correct way to handle this?  If I don't have the classpath in dependencyGraph.gradle, I get ClassNotFound errors.if I do add it, it's in the wrong classloader (presumably).

Comment: Try to remove build script section from your gradle file that is the configuration file for the plugin

Comment: @EugenMartynov  As I said in the original post, if the buildscript is not there, I get compilation errors: e.g.: unable to resolve class com.vanniktech.dependency.graph.generator.DependencyGraphGeneratorPlugin

Comment: Do you have a sample project somewhere to play with?

Comment: @EugenMartynov  sorry for the delay on reply.  I took a step back, and upgraded gradle to 5.6.1 (we had an older version).  That didn't do it.  I realized that the problem was likely I was being lazy, and this code belonged in buildSrc project, rather than an apply from script. So I created that, with a DepGraphGenerators class that defines some statics that I can import in my main project.  That worked, (and is a cleaner solution, anyway).  I'll try to post the full answer, but basically, I just put the dependencies in buildSrc/build.gradle.

Comment: I'm glad that you resolved it!